# What does "out back" mean in this sentence: "It seems there was a little mix up out back."

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, idiomatic-language

This is from a famous TV show [Golden girls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auhCTAJHg2M&list=PLZVOlsj5n3xGMCBAvdvDO9juBK-8wVTk3) (see:11:10-11:15)

**"Well, it seems there was a little mix up out back and Mrs. Clarkson was cremated by mistake."**

I looked **"out back"** up in 4 dictionaries, all of which yielded the same meaning: **"rural areas".** However, this meaning do not seem to sit well with the sentence.

Does **"out back"** here really means **"rural areas"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Out back refers to the non-public areas of a business premises

They may be inside or outside the actual building.

For example, a shoe store might have some shoes on display but others stored in the staff area “out back”, or “out the back” depending on dialect.

In the case of a crematorium, the “front” customer-accessible area is usually a chapel. “Out back” is where the furnace is and the cremations actually happen.

Come to think of it, it can apply to a residential building to - “Can I borrow your lawn mower?” “Sure, it’s out back.”

Answer (score 1):

No, there "out back" means in an area behind a building. In this case, it's probably the area behind the crematorium, where bodies are actually burnt.

It can refer to the area, such as a back yard, behind a dwelling, or to the area behind a store.

[Wiktionary "out back"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_back)
Adverb
*out back* (not comparable)  (US) **Outside, at the back.**
example:  *My car is parked **out back**.*

Comment: The expression meaning _rural areas_ is one word, **outback**, and is mainly Australian.

Comment: "out the back" is a common variant (maybe more usual in the UK), with the same meaning (in the backyard, back workshop, shed, garden, etc).